# C# - Merge XML files

Tags: c#, xml, merge

I have a XML file containing views for a software. This "base file" has the following structure:

```xml
<ViewsFile>
    <Categories>
        <ViewCategory Name="General">
            <Views>
                <View Name="abc">
                    <StoredProcedure>sp_abc</StoredProcedure>
                    <DefaultDisplayName>This is the view abc</DefaultDisplayName>
                </View>
                <View Name="xyz">
                    <StoredProcedure>sp_xyz</StoredProcedure>
                    <DefaultDisplayName>This is the view xyz</DefaultDisplayName>
                </View>
            </Views>
        </ViewCategory>
        <ViewCategory Name="Warehouse">
            <Views>
                <View Name="123">
                    <StoredProcedure>sp_123</StoredProcedure>
                    <DefaultDisplayName>This is the view 123</DefaultDisplayName>
                </View>
            </Views>
        </ViewCategory>
    </Categories>
</ViewsFile>
```

Now I want to write a small tool which lists a directory of some XML files containing only one view each. Those files look like this:

File 1:

```xml
        <ViewCategory Name="Warehouse">
            <Views>
                <View Name="uio">
                    <StoredProcedure>sp_uio</StoredProcedure>
                    <DefaultDisplayName>This is the view uio</DefaultDisplayName>
                </View>
            </Views>
        </ViewCategory>
```

File 2:

```xml
        <ViewCategory Name="General">
            <Views>
                <View Name="bla">
                    <StoredProcedure>sp_bla</StoredProcedure>
                    <DefaultDisplayName>This is the view bla</DefaultDisplayName>
                </View>
            </Views>
        </ViewCategory>
```

Now the user should be able to select one or multiple of those "one view" files to add them to the base file at the correct position.

So for example file 1 should be added under the `<ViewCategory Name="Warehouse"> -> <Views>` and file 2 under `<ViewCategory Name="General"> -> <Views>`.

At the end the base file would look like this:

```xml
<ViewsFile>
    <Categories>
        <ViewCategory Name="General">
            <Views>
                <View Name="abc">
                    <StoredProcedure>sp_abc</StoredProcedure>
                    <DefaultDisplayName>This is the view abc</DefaultDisplayName>
                </View>
                <View Name="xyz">
                    <StoredProcedure>sp_xyz</StoredProcedure>
                    <DefaultDisplayName>This is the view xyz</DefaultDisplayName>
                </View>
                <View Name="bla">
                    <StoredProcedure>sp_bla</StoredProcedure>
                    <DefaultDisplayName>This is the view bla</DefaultDisplayName>
                </View>
            </Views>
            </Views>
        </ViewCategory>
        <ViewCategory Name="Warehouse">
            <Views>
                <View Name="123">
                    <StoredProcedure>sp_123</StoredProcedure>
                    <DefaultDisplayName>This is the view 123</DefaultDisplayName>
                </View>
                <View Name="uio">
                    <StoredProcedure>sp_uio</StoredProcedure>
                    <DefaultDisplayName>This is the view uio</DefaultDisplayName>
                </View>
            </Views>
        </ViewCategory>
    </Categories>
</ViewsFile>
```

Therefore I created the following method, which unfortunately only adds the single view file content at the end of the last category, but not the correct category.

```cs
private void btn_InstallSnippets_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            String singleViewFile = pathToNewViews + @"\" + value;

            var xDoc1 = XDocument.Load(singleViewFile);
            var xDoc2 = XDocument.Load(baseFile);

            if (File.Exists(baseFile))
            {
                var doc1Entries = xDoc1.Descendants("View");

                var cloneEntries = doc1Entries.Select(x => new XElement(x));
                textBox_Test.Text = cloneEntries.ToString();
                xDoc2.Descendants("View").Last().AddAfterSelf(cloneEntries);

                xDoc2.Save(baseFile);

            }



        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Snippets successfully installed.");
        }
```

What do I have to do to find the corresponding category and add the content there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try following xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication166
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FILENAME1 = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        const string FILENAME2 = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(FILENAME1);
            XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(FILENAME2);

            string category1 = (string)doc1.Descendants("ViewCategory").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("Name");
            XElement category = doc.Descendants("ViewCategory").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == category1).FirstOrDefault();

            XElement view1 = doc1.Descendants("View").FirstOrDefault();
            XElement view = category.Descendants("Views").FirstOrDefault();
            view.Add(view1);

            string category2 = (string)doc2.Descendants("ViewCategory").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("Name");
            category = doc.Descendants("ViewCategory").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == category2).FirstOrDefault();

            XElement view2 = doc2.Descendants("View").FirstOrDefault();
            view = category.Descendants("Views").FirstOrDefault();
            view.Add(view2);
        }
    }
 
}
```